# Modifying strings in an array of strings with duplicate keys with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm stuck on a codewars kata on the final step where I need to modify an array's strings and sum the value of duplicate keys. `res=[ '(A : 200)', '(B : 250)', '(B : 890)' ]` should be modified into  `res=[ '(A : 200)', '(B : 1140)']`

I figured out how to select the portion of the string that I want to sum with `res.forEach((x, i) => { x.slice(5, -1)})` but I am absolutely stuck on how to write out and check if `x[1]` appears more than once and how to create a new array that reassigns that specific element by the summation of its `Number(string slice)`.

Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to dissect those strings into their components (key/value). Then create an object keyed by the keys and having initially 0 as corresponding value. Then iterate the data to add the values to the appropriate key, and finally format that result back into your original format.

Of course, if you *produced* those strings, then it is better to first apply this logic, before you format your result.

```js
let res = ['(A : 200)', '(B : 250)', '(B : 890)'];
let pairs = res.map(s => s.match(/\w+/g)); // extract the relevant info
let obj = Object.fromEntries(pairs.map(([k]) => [k, 0])); // start with 0
for (let [k, v] of pairs) obj[k] += +v; // add all values
let result = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => `(${k} : ${v})`); // format

console.log(result);
```

If you don't have support for `Object.fromEntries`, then you can use `Object.assign`:

```js
let res = ['(A : 200)', '(B : 250)', '(B : 890)'];
let pairs = res.map(s => s.match(/\w+/g)); // extract the relevant info
let obj = Object.assign(...pairs.map(([k]) => ({ [k]: 0 }))); // start with 0
for (let [k, v] of pairs) obj[k] += +v; // add all values
let result = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => `(${k} : ${v})`); // format

console.log(result);
```